# save data in cakephp database

Tags: php, database, cakephp

i have a cakephp web app that i'm developing.
I have a UsersController.php file,which handles all users registrations and logins. When a user is logged in,he can use the functionality of FeaturesController.php.
The FueaturesController.php has a view file,the create.ctp . In create.ctp,the user inserts some data into an HTML form and these data are saved into a database,using $this->Modelname->save($this->request->data).

NOW,i want to add into a field of the database the username of the user that did/used that HTML,but till now i have not succeed!
My code looks like this:

```
$username = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');
```

so that i save the username of the user into the variable $username.

But now,how can i insert it into the database? I have tried various ways but it didn't work :/

Anyone's help is welcomed,thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add the username to the form, it's not secure as a malicious user simply has to modify the HTML to change it. Instead, you should set it right before saving:

```
$this->request->data['Modelname']['username'] = $this->Auth->user('username');
$this->Modelname->save($this->request->data);
```

Assuming you're using the authentication component `$this->Auth->user('username');` is the same as `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');` by the way, just a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['modelname']['dbfieldname'] = $username;
$this->modelname->save(data);
```